# rdlc ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found

Tags: asp.net, session, reporting-services

I use javascript to popup reports. but after i popup first one in firefox. I run same repost in chrome it will get " ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found". if I refresh(f5) that reportview page it will show error "
    **An error has occurred during report processing.
        dsRptXXX**"

I already use stateserver to store session.

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20"  />
```

Do you have any suggestion?

I use vs2010, iis7, rdlc reports.The Javascript is like below

```
    function printWindow() {
            var rpt = document.getElementById("cphMain_ddlRpt").value;
            var dept = document.getElementById("cphMain_ddlDept");
            var deptid = dept.value;
            if (deptid == -1) {
                deptName = "";
            }
            var statementdate = document.getElementById("cphMain_ddlStatementDate").value;
            if (rpt == "1")
                openWindow('ViewFReportwP.aspx?DeptID=' + deptid + '&Date=' + statementdate, 'printer', 1280, 1024);
            else if (rpt == "2")
                openWindow('ViewGReportwP.aspx?vDeptDriverID=' + deptid + '&Date=' + statementdate, 'printer', 1280, 1024);
            else
                alert("no parameter");
    }

function openWindow(url, winname, w, h) {
    var nScrW = 1280;
    var nScrH = 1024;
    if (document.all || document.layers) {
        nScrW = screen.availWidth;
        nScrH = screen.availHeight - 60;
    }
    var leftPos = (nScrW - w) / 2;
    var topPos = 0;
    newwin = window.open(url, winname, 'width=' + w + ',height=' + nScrH + ',menu=no,toolbars=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=' + topPos + ',left=' + leftPos);
    newwin.moveTo(leftPos, topPos);
}
```

Comment: Please post your Javascript.

Comment: @Win, I just add javascript to question. Pls check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Nothing about session. it's because I add <%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="DeptID;DateStatement" %> to those report pages trying to speed up the reports.
After I remove them, everything back to normal.

Thank you